# Windows 11 - Security features deactivated after a restart - how to find the cause?

Tags: security, windows-11

I noticed that security features included with Windows 11 Home Edition were deactivated today after a reboot. The reboot was a scheduled reboot, I enabled this when configuring the system. I noticed that 'Core Isolation - Memory Integrity' and 'App & Browser Control' were deactivated. I was able to reenable them I am unsure as to what caused this.

I tried sifting through Windows Event Viewer to look for Errors, Warnings and Criticals under the Windows/Security section; nothing showed. There are thousands of other audit events. I cannot make much sense out of them, I have tried various filters but I have not found what I am looking for.

I am looking for advice on how to diagnose how the settings were changed.

Comment: What is your actual question? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: I have updated, hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: There are a lot of reasons, far too many to even list, as to why Core Isolation would be turned off.

Comment: You can dismiss the warning (Device Security, Core Isolation).  Do that and restart. Windows Defender should show that it is fine. I have not seen that setting work on any computer no matter how new.

Comment: @Ramhound doesn't explain why a security feature that was and can be enabled would be disabled.

Comment: @John This was post-restart, it should not have been disabled.

Comment: @GettingItDone - Kernel drivers must be compatible with Core Isolation, it’s possible to install such software, but in that case the user is explicitly installing something like that. Based on the information we cannot determine the reason Core Isolation was disabled

Comment: I understand but most computers (all that I have seen) do not support Core Isolation, so dismissing it and restarting will leave it dismissed and WD will show all green.